# Quicksort template (for sorting corresponding arrays)

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel, c++14, quick-sort

I needed a function for sorting two corresponding arrays. So I wrote this code to sort N corresponding arrays!

The really "metaprogrammy" way to do it would be to use `std::sort` with a custom `zip_iterator`, but since `zip_iterator`'s `operator*` returns a "proxy reference" type which is not Regular, and `std::sort` doesn't seem to be guaranteed to work with non-Regular types, I decided it would be much safer to build my own quicksort from scratch.

My intent is that `flatmap_detail::sort_together(comparator, ctrs...)` should work for any `ctrs...` which meet the requirements of a random-access container. (So for example I can assume that `ctrs.begin()` and `ctrs.size()` both exist.) I also assume that the `value_type`s involved are all Regular, although perhaps move-only.

---

```
#include <utility> // for std::swap

namespace flatmap_detail {

template<class... Its>
void swap_together(size_t i, size_t j, Its... its)
{
    using std::swap;
    int dummy[] = {
        [&](){
            auto it = its + i;
            auto jt = its + j;
            using std::swap;
            swap(*it, *jt);
            return 0;
        }() ...
    };
    (void)dummy;
}

template<class Predicate, class Head, class... Rest>
size_t partition_together(Predicate& pred, size_t left, size_t right, Head head, const Rest... rest) {
    while (left < right) {
        while (left != right && pred(*(head + left))) ++left;
        while (left != right && !pred(*(head + (right-1)))) --right;
        if (left + 1 < right) {
            flatmap_detail::swap_together(left, right-1, head, rest...);
            ++left;
            --right;
        }
    }
    return right;
}

template<class Compare, class Head, class... Rest>
void sort_together(Compare& less, size_t left, size_t right, Head head, Rest... rest) {
    if (right - left == 2) {
        // I don't like this special case, but I don't want to pay for
        // "swap, partition an array of length 1, swap back" in this
        // common case. Can this special case be subsumed into the
        // general case somehow without losing performance?
        if (less(*(head + left), *(head + (left+1)))) {
            // nothing to do
        } else {
            flatmap_detail::swap_together(left, left+1, head, rest...);
        }
    } else if (right - left >= 3) {
        size_t pivot_idx = left + (right - left) / 2;
        // Swap the pivot element all the way to the right.
        if (pivot_idx != right - 1) {
            flatmap_detail::swap_together(pivot_idx, right-1, head, rest...);
        }
        const auto& pivot_elt = *(head + (right-1));
        auto less_than_pivot = [&](const auto& x) -> bool {
            return less(x, pivot_elt);
        };
        size_t correct_pivot_idx = flatmap_detail::partition_together(less_than_pivot, left, right-1, head, rest...);
        if (correct_pivot_idx != right-1) {
            flatmap_detail::swap_together(correct_pivot_idx, right-1, head, rest...);
        }
        flatmap_detail::sort_together(less, left, correct_pivot_idx, head, rest...);
        flatmap_detail::sort_together(less, correct_pivot_idx+1, right, head, rest...);
    }
}

template<class Compare, class Head, class... Rest>
void sort_together(Compare less, Head& head, Rest&... rest) {
    flatmap_detail::sort_together(less, 0, head.size(), head.begin(), rest.begin()...);
}

} // namespace flatmap_detail
```

---

And here's the test harness I used to try to find the bugs (there were plenty, at first, but I can't find any more now). I know the harness code's style could be bikeshedded to death, so I'm not that interested in comments on its style; but if you see a class of inputs that I'm failing to test adequately, I'd definitely like to know about it.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> iota_vector(int n) {
    std::vector<int> result;
    for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) result.emplace_back(i);
    return result;
}

std::vector<int> random_vector(int n) {
    std::vector<int> result;
    static std::mt19937 g;
    for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) result.emplace_back(g());
    return result;
}

std::vector<int> a, b;

void print_vector(const std::string& who, const std::vector<int>& v) {
    std::cout << who << ":";
    for (int elt : v) {
        std::cout << " " << elt;
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

void print_arrays(const std::string& when) {
    std::cout << when << "\n";
    print_vector("  a", a);
    print_vector("  b", b);
}

int main()
{
    for (int t=0; t < 1000; ++t) {
        for (int n=0; n <= 200; ++n) {
            auto oa = random_vector(n);
            auto ob = iota_vector(n);
            a = oa; b = ob;
            flatmap_detail::sort_together(std::less<int>(), a, b);

            if (!std::is_sorted(a.begin(), a.end(), std::less<int>())) {
                print_arrays("FAILURE!");
                exit(1);
            }
            for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) {
                if (a[i] != oa[b[i]]) {
                    print_arrays("FAILURE!");
                    exit(1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a lot of neat stuff going on there. 1 Question: What was your application for parallel vectors? I learnt a personal lesson decades ago that makes me recoil from parallel vectors. Instead of N vectors should it not be a vector of struct with N members (and an `operator<()` if required)? Also `quicksort` is nice but of course `std::sort` is better for a number of edge cases.   So I wonder what motivated this, and would the suggested refactor to `vector<struct>` have been appropriate?

Comment: My application was an implementation of [P0429 `flat_map`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0429r7.pdf), which is deliberately specified as a pair of vectors instead of a vector of pairs, for "performance." The intuition is that when you search the keys vector, you don't want to waste cache lines loading values alongside them. (The counterargument: binary search is the epitome of a cache-unfriendly algorithm, and any attempt to make it "more cache-friendly" is dumb.) See ["Contra `flat_map`"](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/01/29/contra-flat-map/) (Jan 2019).

Comment: Cool. That makes sense. I mean the reason for `sort_together`. Not necessarily the "optimisation" it brings.

Answer (score 4):

Clean and readable code!  Nice work.

Here's some nitpicks.

## `swap_together`

> ```
> template<class... Its>
> void swap_together(size_t i, size_t j, Its... its)
> {
>     using std::swap;
>     int dummy[] = {
>         [&](){
>             auto it = its + i;
>             auto jt = its + j;
>             using std::swap;
>             swap(*it, *jt);
>             return 0;
>         }() ...
>     };
>     (void)dummy;
> }
> ```

Some observations:

- the redundant `using std::swap;` on the first line can be removed;
- we can use `std::iter_swap(a, b);` (requires `#include <algorithm>`) instead of `using std::swap; swap(*a, *b);`;
- now all the lambda does is `std::iter_swap(its + i, its + j)`, which is an expression; and
- `int[0]` is illegal, so the function should be modified trivially in order to handle the case of `sizeof...(Its) == 0`.

I also like to express the requirement that `Its` are all random access iterators more explicitly.  End result:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>

template <class... RanIts>
void swap_together(std::size_t i, std::size_t j, RanIts... its)
{
    int arr[] = {0, ((void)(std::iter_swap(its + i, its + j)), 0)...};
    (void)arr;
}
```

(The first cast to `void` is to prevent overloaded `operator,`.)

This gets simpler in C++17, with fold expressions:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>

template <class... RanIts>
void swap_together(std::size_t i, std::size_t j, RanIts... its)
{
    ((void)std::iter_swap(its + i, its + j), ...);
}
```

## `partition_together`

> ```
> template<class Predicate, class Head, class... Rest>
> size_t partition_together(Predicate& pred, size_t left, size_t right, Head head, const Rest... rest) {
>     while (left < right) {
>         while (left != right && pred(*(head + left))) ++left;
>         while (left != right && !pred(*(head + (right-1)))) --right;
>         if (left + 1 < right) {
>             flatmap_detail::swap_together(left, right-1, head, rest...);
>             ++left;
>             --right;
>         }
>     }
>     return right;
> }
> ```

We can use some standard algorithms from `<algorithm>` here:

> ```
> while (left != right && pred(*(head + left))) ++left;
> ```

is equivalent to

```
left = std::find_if(head + left, head + right, pred) - head;
```

(There is a signed/unsigned mismatch here; you can add a cast or change the types of `left` and `right`.)

> ```
> while (left != right && !pred(*(head + (right-1)))) --right;
> ```

is equivalent to

```
right = std::find_if_not(
    std::make_reverse_iterator(head + right),
    std::make_reverse_iterator(head + left),
    pred
).base() - head;
```

(Yes, the interface of the STL algorithms is clumsy for complex use cases, but the intent is clearer.)

Note that `left + 1` in the condition to `if` may be `end + 1` because the first nested `while` loop may set `left = end`.  `right - left > 1` is safer.  You can also use postfix increment and prefix decrement:

```
if (right - left > 1) {
    flatmap_detail::swap_together(left++, --right, rest...);
}
```

## `sort_together`

In the majority of cases (size >= 3), two tests are performed: `right - left == 2` and `right - left >= 3`.  Test for `>= 3` first.

Instead of `if (...) { /* nothing to do */ } else`, use the negation operator:

```
if (!less(*(head + left), *(head + (left + 1)))) {
    flatmap_detail::swap_together(left, left + 1, head, rest...);
}
```

The result of invoking a comparator should be *contextually converted* to `bool`; implicit conversion is not guaranteed to work.  So insert a cast here:

> ```
> auto less_than_pivot = [&](const auto& x) -> bool {
>     return less(x, pivot_elt);
> };
> ```

I'm not sure about this:

> ```
> // I don't like this special case, but I don't want to pay for
> // "swap, partition an array of length 1, swap back" in this
> // common case. Can this special case be subsumed into the
> // general case somehow without losing performance?
> ```

## Miscellaneous

- `std::size_t` instead of `size_t`.  Also missing `#include <cstddef>`
- Standard algorithms take comparators and predicates by value.  Your use of references here is probably to avoid copying them too many times around, but the user can choose to use `std::ref` to handle this.