# Sorting multiple vectors based on a reference vector

Tags: c++, sorting, vectors

I am trying to sort vectors based on a reference vector. First I am getting the indexes for the reference vector and then using that I am doing inplace sorting for the rest of the vectors.

```
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using iter = std::vector<int>::iterator;
using order_type = std::vector<std::pair<size_t, iter>>;

void create_permutation(order_type &order)
{
        struct ordering {
                bool operator ()(std::pair<size_t, iter> const& a, std::pair<size_t, iter> const& b) {
                        return *(a.second) < *(b.second);
                }
        };

        std::sort(order.begin(), order.end(), ordering());
}

void reorder(std::vector<int> &vect, order_type index)
{
        for (int i=0; i< vect.size(); i++)
        {
                while (index[i].first != i)
                {
                        int  old_target_idx  = index[index[i].first].first;
                        int old_target_v  = vect[index[i].first];

                        vect[index[i].first] = vect[i];
                        index[index[i].first].first = index[i].first;

                        index[i].first = old_target_idx;
                        vect[i]   = old_target_v;
                }
        }
}

template<typename... argtype>
void sort_from_ref(argtype... args);

template<typename T, typename A, typename... argtype>
void sort_from_ref(order_type order, std::vector<T,A> &vect, argtype &&...args)
{
        reorder(vect, order);
        sort_from_ref(order, std::forward<argtype>(args)...);
}

template<>
void sort_from_ref(order_type order, std::vector<int> &vect) {
        reorder(vect, order);
}

int main()
{
        size_t n = 0;
        std::vector<int> vect_1{ 1, 0, 2, 3 };
        std::vector<int> vect_2{ 100, 200, 300, 400 };
        std::vector<int> vect_3{ 100, 200, 300, 400 };
        std::vector<int> vect_4{ 400, 200, 3000, 4000 };
        std::vector<int> vect_5{ 500, 200, 360, 400 };
        order_type order(vect_1.size());

        for (iter it = vect_1.begin(); it != vect_1.end(); ++it) {
                order[n] = std::make_pair(n, it);
                n++;
        }
        create_permutation(order);
        sort_from_ref(order, vect_2, vect_3, vect_4, vect_5);

        {
                std::vector<int> test{200, 100, 300, 400};
                assert(vect_2 == test);
        }
        {
                std::vector<int> test{200, 100, 300, 400};
                assert(vect_3 == test);
        }
        {
                std::vector<int> test{200, 400, 3000, 4000};
                assert(vect_4 == test);
        }
        {
                std::vector<int> test{200, 500, 360, 400};
                assert(vect_5 == test);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Question: What was your application/motivation for parallel vectors? I learnt a personal lesson decades ago that makes me recoil from parallel vectors. Instead of N vectors should it not be a vector of struct with N members (and an operator<() if required)? The idea being that what belongs together should be kept together.

Comment: @OliverSchönrock Keeping/Putting them together might, among others, have these detrimental effects: 1. Increase memory required due to alignment. 2. Decrease locality in some later algorithm. 3. Require packing/unpacking or changing source/sink. Whether any of those effects happen and are important enough, so destructured data becomes a good idea, is a judgement call, and might want measuring.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yes. those are fair points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For another take on the same problem (sorting parallel arrays), see [Quicksort template (for sorting corresponding arrays)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/212711/quicksort-template-for-sorting-corresponding-arrays).

Your code is strangely organized. I would expect it to have a single entry point, something like this:

```
template<class Vector, class... Vectors>
void parallel_sort(Vector& keyvector, Vectors&... vectors) {
    std::vector<size_t> order(keyvector.size());
    std::iota(order.begin(), order.end(), 0);
    std::sort(order.begin(), order.end(), [&](size_t a, size_t b) {
        return keyvector[a] < keyvector[b];
    });
    (reorder(keyvector, order) , ... , reorder(vectors, order));
}
```

(Hey, look at that! It's a complete implementation, except for the `reorder` function you already wrote!)

But instead you require the calling code to set up their own `order` vector manually, then call `create_permutation`, then `sort_from_ref`, in that order. That's a lot of steps. At the very least, you could provide a function `create_order_vector` to simplify that first step.

---

The one advantage I can see to requiring the caller to provide the `order` vector is that it allows your library code to do no heap allocations. Vice versa, a problem with my code above is that it requires O(n) memory to sort n elements. If I have a million-element vector, I need to heap-allocate *another* eight million bytes to sort it! That could be annoying or prohibitive for some callers — they might not expect a sorting function to throw `std::bad_alloc`. At least by making the caller allocate the eight million bytes themselves, you're putting the issue front and center where they can't miss it.

---

I think it's strange that you define the alias `order_type` to be `std::vector<std::pair<size_t, iter>>`. I would rather see

```
using order_type = std::pair<size_t, iter>;

[...] std::vector<order_type> order;
```

Again, I guess it comes down to my wanting to see `std::vector`-ness explicitly in the code. I have the same complaint about typedefs such as `using Foo = foo*;` that hide a type's pointer-ness.

---

```
template<typename T, typename A, typename... argtype>
void sort_from_ref(order_type order, std::vector<T,A> &vect, argtype &&...args)
{
        reorder(vect, order);
        sort_from_ref(order, std::forward<argtype>(args)...);
}
```

In C++17, you can use a comma-operator fold-expression to do this, as I did above. But even in C++11, you can use a pack expansion to do this without all the "recursive template" stuff. (See ["Iteration is better than recursion."](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/07/23/metafilter/)) You'd just do something like this:

```
template<class... Args>
void sort_from_ref(order_type order, Args&... args)
{
    int dummy[] = {
        [&]() { reorder(args, order); return 0; } ...
    };
}
```

Notice that I also changed `argtype` to `Args`. It's a pack of *multiple* argtypes, not just one; and the C++ convention for template parameters is to CamelCase them.

I also eliminated your perfect forwarding. We *know* that all our `args` are going to be non-const lvalue references; so we should just say so.

We also know that all our `args` are going to be `std::vector<T>` for some `T`, because that's the only kind of argument that will be accepted by our `reorder` template. Therefore, it is incorrect (but largely harmless) that you wrote

```
template<typename T, typename A, [...]>
void sort_from_ref([...] std::vector<T,A> &vect, [...]
```

because there is only one possible `A` that can go there and have the code still compile. You should just have said

```
template<typename T, typename... argtype>
void sort_from_ref(order_type order, std::vector<T>& vect, argtype&&... args)
```

(except that, as we've seen, you don't need this "recursive" template at all).

---

No comment on your `reorder` function; that part is all math. (Does it work? Did you test it exhaustively?)

Okay, two comments...

```
                    index[i].first = old_target_idx;
                    vect[i]   = old_target_v;
```

Your whitespace here (and other places) is wonky. It looks like maybe you were trying to align the `=` signs, but failed? I strongly recommend *not* trying to align anything, ever. It's not robust against refactoring. (For example, if you change the name of a variable, now you have to realign everything it touched.)

```
for (int i=0; i< vect.size(); i++)
```

You should be getting a stupid warning from your compiler about "comparing signed and unsigned" here. If you're not, then turn up your warning levels — you should be using `-W -Wall` (and maybe `-Wextra`) on non-MSVC compilers, and I'd say `-W4` on MSVC. The traditional workaround would be to make `i` a `size_t` instead of an `int`.

Comment: possible to explain this (reorder(keyvector, order) , ... , reorder(vectors, order)); ? Also, I did make_pair in the main function because I need the iterator to be alive until the execution also didn't want the function to allocate memory.

Comment: Query: "strongly recommend not trying to align anything, ever. It's not robust against refactoring" . I see your point, however, appropriate, logical and consistent whitespace can significantly add to readability. So some teams (and me personally) use options like .clang-format: "AlignConsecutiveAssignments: true" and "AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: true".  This makes the refactor point mute (apart from a larger vcs diff). In certain sections of code where custom whitespace significantly adds to meaning I even `//clang-format off`, but try to avoid this for the reason you gave.

Comment: @user3053970, `(reorder(keyvector, order) , ... , reorder(vectors, order));` is just a call to `reorder(keyvector, order)` and a fold-expression that expands `reorder(vectors, order)` connected by the comma operator.  All the results are discarded, as they must be when calling a `void`-returning function.  It could be written as separate statements, but that would hide the symmetry.

Comment: iota shouldn't be neccesary for this, it doubles the memory usage

Answer (score 4):

If you ahead of time know the number of arrays/vectors then with ranges-v3 you can do exactly what the OP was trying to achieve.

> sort vectors based on a reference vector

With ranges-v3 you can zip multiple ranges together and sort based on a projection onto just one of those ranges. **This would reduce/remove code maintenance of a custom solution**.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>

#include "range/v3/all.hpp"

namespace r = ranges;
namespace rv = r::views;

int main()
{
    {
        auto order = std::vector{  1,   0,    3,    2};
        auto v1    = std::vector{100, 200,  300,  400};
        auto v2    = std::vector{100, 200,  300,  400};
        auto v3    = std::vector{400, 200, 3000, 4000};
        auto v4    = std::vector{500, 200,  360,  400};

        r::sort(
            rv::zip(order, v1, v2, v3, v4), 
            std::less{}, 
            [](auto && p){ return std::get<0>(p); }
        );

        assert((order == std::vector{  0,   1,    2,    3}));
        assert((v1    == std::vector{200, 100,  400,  300}));
        assert((v2    == std::vector{200, 100,  400,  300}));
        assert((v3    == std::vector{200, 400, 4000, 3000}));
        assert((v4    == std::vector{200, 500,  400,  360}));
    }
    {
        auto order = std::vector{5, 4, 3, 2, 0, 1};
        auto v1    = std::vector{3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1};
        auto v2    = std::vector{6, 5, 2, 1, 3, 4};

        r::sort(
            rv::zip(order, v1, v2),
            std::less{},
            [](auto && p){ return std::get<0>(p); }
        );

        assert((order == std::vector{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}));
        assert((v1    == std::vector{1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3}));
        assert((v2    == std::vector{3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 6}));
    }
}
```

---

Side note: fix-up/modification of Oliver Schönrock's version

- still only one instance of the index
- handles cycles of swaps correctly
- special control follow for optimizations

````
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>

#include "range/v3/all.hpp"

namespace r = ranges;
namespace rv = r::views;
namespace ra = r::actions;

template <typename Comp, typename Vec, typename... Vecs>
void parallel_sort(Comp && comp, Vec& keyvec, Vecs&... vecs)
{
    auto const len = keyvec.size();

    (assert(len == vecs.size()), ...);

    auto const byKey = [&](auto i) { return keyvec[i]; };
    auto index = rv::iota(std::size_t{0u}, len) 
               | r::to_vector
               | ra::sort(comp, byKey);

    for (std::size_t i = 0u; /**/; ++i)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (i == len) return;   // reached the end
            if (index[i] == i) ++i; // skip cycles of size one (avoid unnecessary writes)
            else break;             // found start of a cycle
        }

        // move members around the current cycle
        auto from = i;
        while (true)
        {
            auto const to = std::exchange(index[from], from);
            // back at start of the cycle, go find next cycle
            if (to == i) break;

            std::swap(keyvec[from], keyvec[to]);
            (std::swap(vecs[from], vecs[to]), ...);
            from = to;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    {
        auto order = std::vector{  1,   0,    3,    2};
        auto v1    = std::vector{100, 200,  300,  400};
        auto v2    = std::vector{100, 200,  300,  400};
        auto v3    = std::vector{400, 200, 3000, 4000};
        auto v4    = std::vector{500, 200,  360,  400};

        parallel_sort(std::less{}, order, v1, v2, v3, v4);

        assert((order == std::vector{  0,   1,    2,    3}));
        assert((v1    == std::vector{200, 100,  400,  300}));
        assert((v2    == std::vector{200, 100,  400,  300}));
        assert((v3    == std::vector{200, 400, 4000, 3000}));
        assert((v4    == std::vector{200, 500,  400,  360}));
    }
    {
        auto order = std::vector{5, 4, 3, 2, 0, 1};
        auto v1    = std::vector{3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1};
        auto v2    = std::vector{6, 5, 2, 1, 3, 4};

        parallel_sort(std::less{}, order, v1, v2);

        assert((order == std::vector{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}));
        assert((v1    == std::vector{1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3}));
        assert((v2    == std::vector{3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 6}));
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Do you need to know "ahead of time"? Can you not just wrap your Rv3 code in a function taking a param pack and then expand that in the call to r3:zip, similar to my example?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, refer my comment under your question: "Is there a good reason for parallel vectors at all? Or should it be a single vector of `struct {int, int, ...}`?"

Assuming there is a good reason: Putting it all together, applying consistent style and making a few optimising tweak...

I have "borrowed" from @Quuxplusone for the `parallel_sort` with C++17 ["comma operator" fold expression to expand the parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold). (He is using option (2) on that page, with "op" = ",").

No more need for the pair because the information is in the "array index position" after the sorting is done.

I changed your `3-way old_target_*` to `std:swap` and changed the `while` to an `if`. That's the same no?

A utility function makes the testing cleaner.

Code formatting using [my standard `.clang-format`](https://github.com/oschonrock/stamp/blob/master/.clang-format). You may disagree with this config, but it is consistent.

A type alias for the `value_t` = `int` just in case you want to change it. It could be templated, but this would get complicated and might be overkill?

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <cassert>

using std::size_t;
using value_t = int;

void reorder(std::vector<value_t>& vect, std::vector<size_t> index) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++) {
    if (index[i] != i) {
      std::swap(vect[index[i]], vect[i]);
      std::swap(index[index[i]], index[i]);
    }
  }
}

template <typename Vector, typename... Vectors>
void parallel_sort(Vector& keyvector, Vectors&... vectors) {
  std::vector<size_t> index(keyvector.size());
  std::iota(index.begin(), index.end(), 0);
  std::sort(index.begin(), index.end(),
            [&](size_t a, size_t b) { return keyvector[a] < keyvector[b]; });

  (reorder(keyvector, index), ..., reorder(vectors, index));
}

void test(const std::vector<value_t>& vec, const std::vector<value_t>& res) { 
  assert(vec == res); 
}

value_t main() {
  std::vector<value_t> order{1, 0, 3, 2};
  std::vector<value_t> v1{100, 200, 300, 400};
  std::vector<value_t> v2{100, 200, 300, 400};
  std::vector<value_t> v3{400, 200, 3000, 4000};
  std::vector<value_t> v4{500, 200, 360, 400};

  parallel_sort(order, v1, v2, v3, v4);

  test(v1, {200, 100, 400, 300});
  test(v2, {200, 100, 400, 300});
  test(v3, {200, 400, 4000, 3000});
  test(v4, {200, 500, 400, 360});
}
```

My only other thought on this solution is that it does a lot of copying. Not only does it construct the index, but then it makes a copy of that index, as a working area, for each vector it sorts. For small vectors this is absolutely fine. But for big structures you might want to follow @Quuxplusone's other quicksort approach.

Alternatively we should consider refactoring the code above, such that it only runs through reorder() once, ie it only needs one "copy" of index (and therefore doesn't actually need a copy, because it can be discarded after that single swap run).

See final code below for the relevant changes:

- No more reorder function, just a `std::swap` wrapper to swap specific elements of a vector.
- This `swap_elements` is called once for each vector in the pack, in
  the inner loop, using the now familiar fold expression.
- Added a fold expression `assert()` to ensure the vectors are all the same size and thus prevent UB.
- As a bonus the code is now so simple that we can easily add  deduction, ie vectors of anything.
- Bonus #2: Add the `std::less<>` as the first param, so you can reverse sort or similar.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

using std::size_t;

template <typename T>
void swap(size_t i, size_t j, std::vector<T>& v) {
  std::swap(v[i], v[j]);
}

template <typename Comp, typename Vec, typename... Vecs>
void parallel_sort(const Comp& comp, Vec& keyvec, Vecs&... vecs) {
  (assert(keyvec.size() == vecs.size()), ...);
  std::vector<size_t> index(keyvec.size());
  std::iota(index.begin(), index.end(), 0);
  std::sort(index.begin(), index.end(),
            [&](size_t a, size_t b) { return comp(keyvec[a], keyvec[b]); });

  for (size_t i = 0; i < index.size(); i++) {
    if (index[i] != i) {
      (swap(index[i], i, keyvec), ..., swap(index[i], i, vecs));
      std::swap(index[index[i]], index[i]);
    }
  }
}

template <typename T>
void test(const std::vector<T>& vec, const std::vector<T>& res) {
  assert(vec == res);
}

int main() {
  using value_t = int;
  using vec_t   = std::vector<value_t>;

  vec_t order{1, 0, 3, 2};
  vec_t v1{100, 200, 300, 400};
  vec_t v2{100, 200, 300, 400};
  vec_t v3{400, 200, 3000, 4000};
  vec_t v4{500, 200, 360, 400};

  parallel_sort(std::less<>(), order, v1, v2, v3, v4);

  test(v1, vec_t{200, 100, 400, 300});
  test(v2, vec_t{200, 100, 400, 300});
  test(v3, vec_t{200, 400, 4000, 3000});
  test(v4, vec_t{200, 500, 400, 360});
}
```

- [CppInsights link](https://cppinsights.io/s/16c0a5a8) which shows us the templates which get instantiated. You can clearly see the way the fold expression gets expanded:

```
(((swap_elements(index.operator[](i), i, keyvector) , 
  swap_elements(index.operator[](i), i, __vectors1)) , 
  swap_elements(index.operator[](i), i, __vectors2)) , 
  swap_elements(index.operator[](i), i, __vectors3)) , 
 swap_elements(index.operator[](i), i, __vectors4);
```

This code could work well for quite large vectors.

**Correction**

There is a bug above. As pointed out in comment below from @Gareth A. Lloyd

Correct implementation at CE link provided by him:
https://godbolt.org/z/ev38MWdTb

Comment: Good catch on `reorder` making a copy of `index`! I hadn't looked close enough at `reorder` to notice that.

Comment: I think there's a way to get rid of the `index` vector, by creating a `template<class KeyVector, class... Vectors> class parallel_vector` that basically wraps multiple vectors, and defines iterators, `begin()`, `end()` etc. such that using `std::sort()` on an instance of that class would sort all vectors at once based on the key vector. The tricky part will be the iterator, which should be such that `std::swap(*it1, *it2)` does the right thing.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds feasible. However, as I said elsewhere I am yet to be convinced that parallel vectors are a useful tool (except perhaps in HP lib code such as Athur was trying to build here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/212711/quicksort-template-for-sorting-corresponding-arrays and maybe some other obscure examples). For general use ... make a struct and sort that? Or if you can't change your design, probably BoostMultiIndex can do this?

Comment: parallel vectors occur in any code that needs SIMD -- games, HPC, informatics, etc

Comment: In your 2nd code I believe the `if (index[i] != i)` should be `while (index[i] != i)`

Comment: @GarethA.Lloyd I haven't checked this for a while, but I think gets there just with the `if`  and should be slightly faster as less "NOP iterations" of the out loop? Tests seem to pass.

Comment: @OliverSchönrock (replicating chat from fosstodon) I actually realize now it is actually more than changing an `if`. Here is a test case that doesn't work https://godbolt.org/z/noen8fzT8

Comment: @OliverSchönrock (replicating chat from fosstodon) your index tells you for each position where the correct value should be retrieved from.

Once you have swapped, whoever needed the value that was at position 0 has no idea where to find it (unless that swap was with the one that needed position 0). 

So your index is not tolerant to values being moved around, so you need to make an inverse map first. And because of that you can't directly move a value to its intended destination, you have to handle whole cycles of moves. Hence the while loop.

Comment: For reference here is what I believe to be a correct implementation https://godbolt.org/z/ev38MWdTb